# How do I tell alltt environment to wrap text?

Tags: listings, verbatim

I have an already formatted text (space-wise) that is also being colored etc, so I am using `alltt` environment to print it. The text is code actually, but I am not using listings because I don't want it to color my code (I am doing the coloring based on which line is important so it's different).

Problem is now, I can't figure a way to tell `alltt` to wrap the text. It would eventually look ugly if the text is wrapped, but it is even more ugly if they go out of the right border of the page!!

So, is there a way to wrap text with `alltt`? If no, is it possible to get text that has styles (such as `\textit{...}` etc) with the listings package?

**Edit:** Here is an example:

Preamble (some styling):

```
\newcommand{\somewhatImportantCode}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.35,0.6}{#1}}
\newcommand{\veryImportantCode}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.5,0.9}{#1}}
```

Code:

```
\begin{alltt}
\somewhatImportantCode{\#include <iostream>}

int main()
\{
  \veryImportantCode{std::cout <<} "Hello World!" \veryImportantCode{<< std::endl};
  return 0;
\}
\end{alltt}
```

And here is how it looks like:

[image]

Note that that goal is to direct the user to parts of the code that are more significant and that's why its styling is different. As you can see, the `\somewhatImportantCode` and `\veryImportantCode` could cover any short or long part of the code.

Comment: You can surely customize how `listings` marks the code so that nothing it coloured. Maybe you should post a small `listings` example document with what kind of line-based colouring you are using and ask the listings question directly.

Comment: @AlanMunn, There seems to be a lot on `listings` on the internet and if there is no way to wrap text in `alltt`, I don't think I would have a problem figuring out how to make it work with `listings`. So, let's first see if wrapping text is possible with `alltt`. If not, then I'll try to figure `listings` myself

Comment: @AlanMunn, you are right, I removed the P.S. which looked as if I wanted to switch to `listings`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `listings` you just need to add `breaklines=true` to enable line breaking, you can also include commands that are to be executed by defining an `escapechar` which lets you put custom formatting commands.

[image]

If you don't want the italics formatting applied to the keywords, just remove the setting `keywordstyle={}`.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\somewhatImportantCode}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.35,0.6}{#1}}
\newcommand{\veryImportantCode}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.5,0.9}{#1}}

\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  keywordstyle={\textit},
  %morekeywords={text},% list your attributes here, 
  escapechar=\&% char to escape out of listings and back to LaTeX
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
&\somewhatImportantCode{\#include <iostream>}&

int main()
{
  &\veryImportantCode{std::cout <<}& "Hello World!" &\veryImportantCode{<< std::endl}&;
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the wrap in `listings` was not my problem. If `alltt` fails to wrap text, I need to know if `listings` can substitute it, that is, whether `listings` can accept commands, like `\textit{...}`?

Comment: Have updated the solution to show how to apply styles with listings.

Comment: Alright let me put an example in the question to show what I need (give me 5 minutes)

Comment: Interesting work with `&`. So how do you come back into `lstlisting`? Have you noticed that your `text`s are not being emphasized after the styled `some`?

Comment: @Shahbaz: Thanks. I noticed that and corrected it in the new version which uses the OP's code.

Comment: The OP thanks you for your time and effort :D, I would definitely use this.

Comment: Could I ask you one more thing? I tried with `&` and where in my code I have `\&`, it still sees it as an escapechar and gives me error. I thought about switching from `&` to something else, but any character would have the same problem if I cannot escape it with `\`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Best would be to find a character where you don't have this issue. Alternatively, try `&\&&`. This worked for me in the small example.  Of course you could use `\newcommand{\ampersand}{\&}`, and then `&\ampersand&` might be more readable.  If that does not solve you problem, perhaps post a new question.

Comment: For future reference: I don't know how, but somehow the problem with `\&` went away and this method worked perfect. Since my `alltt` environment was less verbatim than `lstlisting` (for example needing `\` for `#`, `{` or `_`), I put every line between `&`s and there was no actual change needed. Also note that the opening `&` must come after the indenting whitespaces and not before.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the OP has already accepted the answer of Peter, I would like to suggest the following improvement: It uses `listings` `moredelim=**` feature to define active chars that turn on and off a certain formatting. Thereby, escaping to LaTeX and poluting the source code with macros is not necessary:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\somewhatImportantCode}{\color[rgb]{0.0,0.35,0.6}}
\newcommand{\veryImportantCode}{\color[rgb]{0.0,0.5,0.9}}

\lstset{
  language=C,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  keywordstyle={\textit},
  moredelim=**[is][\somewhatImportantCode]{@}{@},
  moredelim=**[is][\veryImportantCode]{@@}{@@},
  moredelim=**[is][\color{red}]{@@@}{@@@},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
@#include <iostream>  
@
int main()
{
  @@std::cout <<@@ "Hello World!" @@<< std::endl@@;
  return @@@0@@@;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I have used sequence of `@` for the different levels of emphasis here, but you can use any (sequence of) character(s) for each; if you prefer, even different ones for "emphasis on" and "emphasis off" (see page 30 of the [`listings` manual](http://ftp.uni-erlangen.de/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)).

An additional plus is that (depending on the options used for `moredelim=**`) the formatting can be applied *on top* of each other and of the syntax formatting already provided by `listings`. In the example, this can be seen for the `#include` directive, which gets the "ImportantCode" color additionally to the `\textit` formatting of keywords:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: This is great thanks. However, in my case the previous one is even simpler. I am generating those tex files from another source and so pouring out macros is not a big deal. Either way, it would be writing the macro or it's shortcut which programming-wise, is no different.