# How do I get colorized syntax highlighted code in pdfLaTeX

Tags: highlighting, syntax, code

I'd like to get syntax highlighted code in LaTeX, but want to preserve the monospaced font (no curly quotes either). pygments doesn't seem to have an option to avoid curly quotes that I could find.

Edit:

```
\mint{python}|'banana'|
```

Produces curly single quotes.

Comment: Have you tried `minted` package?

Comment: Do you know the [listings](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package?

Comment: Yes, ``minted`` produces the correct double quotes but not single ones.

Comment: +1, good question, never noticed that. Incidentally, this is unrelated to Pygments, the culprit is fancyvrb.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Is there any way to fix this in minted? I prefer its style over listings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package. Adding this code to the header loads the package and sets the font to be monospace for the source code. I use a black and white printer, so highlighting isn't enabled here. There are options for setting keyword colors in the package documentation.

```
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
         basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, 
         numberstyle=\tiny,          
         numbersep=5pt,             
         tabsize=2,                
         extendedchars=true,      
         breaklines=true,        
         showspaces=false,      
         showtabs=false,       
         xleftmargin=17pt,
         framexleftmargin=17pt,
         framexrightmargin=5pt,
         framexbottommargin=4pt,
         showstringspaces=false 
 }
 \lstloadlanguages{
         Python
 }
```

Then the code can be included using `\lstinputlisting[language=python]{src/main.py}`.

Comment: listings is great. Also if you (@nt01) want to do additional manual coloring, take a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36809/9714) I got from a question of mine.

Comment: I'm going to accept this, but if you can add how to do this with minted, that would be excellent.